# Column Resizer not working when a column is frozen

Tags: javascript, vue.js, primevue

I'm using a PrimeVue table component(https://primevue.org/datatable/#api.datatable.events.DataTableColumnResizeEndEvent) and there is the first column is frozen when I try to resize the frozen column it doesn't work. other columns that are not frozen are resized perfectly.

I'm using a PrimeVue table component(https://primevue.org/datatable/#api.datatable.events.DataTableColumnResizeEndEvent) and there is the first column is frozen when I try to resize the frozen column it doesn't work. other columns that are not frozen are resized perfectly.
here is the link of example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ythpnk?file=src%2FApp.vue